# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred

Tags: node.js, deployment, gcloud, app.yaml

Well, I found many possible solutions but none of them worked for me, some solutions fix the issue but give another issue.
app.yaml

```
includes:
  - prod-env.yaml
runtime: nodejs16
```

When I run the server locally everything works perfectly.
the rest is here -> https://github.com/vovafish/personal-site/tree/main/back-end

I tried changing nodejs to v. 10 and it fixed the issue [13] but it gave me issue [9] it started complaining 'bout using modules instead of CommonJS, this line (import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";).

Are there any solutions to fix the issue and keep es6 (modules) syntax?
Btw, billing is enabled.